# Intuitively similar queries result in different results

Tags: mongodb

In the `sample_training` database, `companies` collection, there is data like the following one:

> [image]

**Exercise:** How many companies in the `sample_training.companies` collection have offices in the city of "*Seattle*"?

---

The query I thought of was with the dot notation as follows:

```
db.companies.find({ "offices.0.city": "Seattle" }).count()
```

This returns `110`.

However, the site gives the following query as the correct one

```
db.companies.find({ "offices": { "$elemMatch": { "city": "Seattle" } } }).count()
```

This returns `117`.

---

I have checked that my query seems to work fine as well, but I don't know why they differ in their result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is you are ***only*** looking at the first element (index 0) in the array. You are specifying the index to look at.

Meaning, if we have the following database:

```
[
  {
    "offices": [
      {
        "city": "Dallas"
      },
      {
        "city": "Jacksonville"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

With the following query:

```
db.collection.find({
  "offices.0.city": "Jacksonville"
})
```

It would return nothing.

Whereas, if we used this query, the element does not have to be the first index.

```
db.collection.find({
  "offices": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "city": "Jacksonville"
    }
  }
})
```

Live Demos:

Working - https://mongoplayground.net/p/wnX-arcooa7

Not Working - https://mongoplayground.net/p/zFWV00TzZjj

Answer (score 0):

I went to the wine db - https://www.pdbmbook.com/playground/mongo/wine/view/pgdb____1635519319_617c0b57588c7

And I did:

```
db.products.find( { "type": "rose"}).count(); 
Result = 3 
db.products.find({ "products.0.type": "rose" }).count();
Result: 0
db.products.find({ "products": { "$elemMatch": { "type": "rose" } } }).count()
Result: 0
```

I suspect I get back 0 since the online playground I used is limited in functionality. Nevertheless I would assume any field that references the index of the object e.g. "offices.0.city" would mean you are starting the count higher up the tree or at 0.